# How to open default browser in windows store 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have an app needs to open a browser and link to the address that I want. My project is coded on windows 8.1. I have research on google but I couldn't find any solutions. 
This code below is good when dev in Windows Phone:

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("link"));
```

But in tablet,it made my app hidden and didn't do anything else.

Please give me any solutions for this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. I have checked and its working fine.

```
LauncherOptions options = new LauncherOptions();
options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
options.TreatAsUntrusted = true;
var success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("Your Link"), options);
```

Here, if you remove `options.DisplayApplicationPicker=true` then it will open default browser. I added that line because it helps user to select different apps each time.